# React Material UI Typography underline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how can I make text with underlining without having `enter` or a new line?

```
   <Typography sx={{ 
          top: '104px',
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          lineHeight: '24px',
          fontSize: '16px',
          letterSpacing: '0.18px',
          color: '#172B4D',
          margin: '16px 0px'
       }}>
      The big brown fox jumps over the <Typography sx={{textDecoration: 'underline'}}>lazy </Typography> dog
      </Typography>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `display="inline"`

```
<Typography sx={{ 
          top: '104px',
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          lineHeight: '24px',
          fontSize: '16px',
          letterSpacing: '0.18px',
          color: '#172B4D',
          margin: '16px 0px'
       }}>
      The big brown fox jumps over the <Typography sx={{textDecoration: 'underline'}} display="inline">lazy </Typography> dog
      </Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native HTML tag [`<u>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u).

> The `<u>` HTML element represents a span of inline text which should be rendered in a way that indicates that it has a non-textual annotation. This is **rendered by default as a simple solid underline**, but may be altered using CSS.

It inherits attributes of `Typography` such as `fontWeight`, `fontStyle` and `sx`.

```
<Typography sx={{ 
  top: '104px',
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  lineHeight: '24px',
  fontSize: '16px',
  letterSpacing: '0.18px',
  color: '#172B4D',
  margin: '16px 0px'
}}>
  The big brown fox jumps over the <u>lazy</u> dog
</Typography>
```

Note: it is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u#avoiding_u) to use `<u>` without implying any semantic meaning.

> To underline text without implying any semantic meaning, use a `<span>` element with the `text-decoration` property set to "underline".

But it just works.